# Customize Python Script On Azure ML

Tags: azure, fuzzy-search, azure-machine-learning-service, fuzzywuzzy, ml-studio

I want to use Fuzzywuzzy logic on python script. I am implement in this way but i didn't get anything.

[image: Azure ML Studio]

This is my python script code:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None):    
return dataframe1,

def get_matches(query, choice, limit = 6):
result = process.extract(query, choice, limit = limit)
return result,

get_matches("admissibility", dataframe1)
```

Comment: Can you maybe add the details of the error that you have on the Python script module?